# Creating Person Class with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, class, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm starting to learn Objective-C and I want to create a simple Person class with name, photo, address (house number, street name, postal code, city), phone.

I'm not sure if I have to use NSArray or NSDictionary for the address attribute. I already created a Person class and I placed my code in Person.h

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *photo;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *address;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *phone;
```

Comment: No @user4261201 create another custom model class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The address should not be an `NSArray` or an `NSDictionary`. It should be another custom class `Address`. This class should then have its own attributes for `house number`, `street name`, `postal code`, `city`, `country`, etc.

If you want a person to have more than one address, then `address` should be a dictionary where the keys are labels for each address and the values are instance of `Address`.

Your `phone` property should also be a dictionary if you wish to support more than one phone number per person.

You should look at the `CNContact` and related classes for examples of how Apple does it.

Comment: This is the best solution. My solution below is more loosely bound and does not give proper structure to the Address as an entity.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this and let you know if it works :)

Comment: Should it be a Subclass of NSObject or Person?

Comment: I assume you are asking about the `Address` class. Since an Address isn't a Person, the `Address` class should be a subclass of `NSObject`.